# Failied to :make install: Linux kernel module SSL error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, openssl, linux-device-driver

Can't install any linux driver (kde neon 5.18)

example:

> ```
> root@Casual-PC:/home/casual/veikk-linux-driver# make all install
> make -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/build
> M=/home/casual/veikk-linux-driver modules make[1]: Entering directory
> '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic'   Building
> modules, stage 2.   MODPOST 1 modules make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic' make -C
> /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/build M=/home/casual/veikk-linux-driver
> modules_install make[1]: Entering directory
> '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic'   INSTALL
> /home/casual/veikk-linux-driver/veikk.ko At main.c:160:
> - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
> - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79 sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such
> file or directory   DEPMOD  5.3.0-42-generic Warning: modules_install:
> missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod. make[1]: Leaving
> directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic' modprobe
> veikk modprobe: FATAL: Module veikk not found in directory
> /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic Makefile:14: recipe for target
> 'install' failed make: *** [install] Error 1
> ```

Comment: Have you tried to install a different kernel version? Do you have the same issue?

Comment: I will try. But I guess this will be the same.

Comment: Looks like your kernel requires signed modules and you don't have the signing key.  https://superuser.com/q/1214116/127177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is some SSL error in default KDE's linux kernel. When i upgraded to newer custom kernel I hadn't ssl error

also [this](https://github.com/jlam55555/veikk-linux-driver/issues/27) may help you

```
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe (your driver name in my case veikk)
sudo make all install clean
```